# Formatting yearmon function of package zoo in r

Tags: r

I'm using the yearmon function

```
library(zoo)
test<-as.Date(c("2015-12-25","2015-11-01"))
test<-as.Date(test,"%y-%m-%d")
test<-as.yearmon(test,"%y-%m")
test
```

Output

```
"Dec 2015" "Nov 2015"
```

I would like the output to be 2015 Nov. The reason I want this is because I use this to create a heat plot and Dec 2015 shows up in the sequence before Nov 2015 because the variable gets sorted on D. Image of the problem attached

[Image of the issue for a larger dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyk3u.png)

Comment: Note that `sort(as.yearmon(c("2015-12-25","2015-11-01")))` sorts correctly (Nov before Dec).  Please show the actual code you are trying to use in a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a format method for yearmon class:

```
> format(test, "%Y %b")
[1] "2015 Dec" "2015 Nov"
```

The `yearmon`-objects are actually stored as fractional years

```
> as.numeric(test)
[1] 2015.917 2015.833
```

I believe that `format.yearmon` calls `format.Date` or `format.POSIXt` after coercion as determined by the contents of the 'format' string.